# How to change CommitBatchSize and CommitBatchThreshold

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

We have a transactional replication set and we want to change CommitBatchThreshold but couldn't find a proper documentation on how to change it. Would adding '-CommitBatchThreshold 10' to the Steps would work in Agent Properties?

Wanna be sure before changing everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, adding the parameters and parameter values to the Steps page in the Agent Properties will work.  Note that if you are running the Distribution Agent continuously then you will need to restart the replication agent for the changes to take affect.